# Restsharp parameter behavior when setting ParameterType=GetOrPost

Tags: c#, restsharp

I face a weird intermittent issue with RestSharp. I use it to submit a POST authentication  request to a server. But under certain conditions that I cannot isolate yet, this authentication call fails. By looking at the server log, I see a GET request instead of a POST. And I really wonder how the hell it is possible.

Here is the code to submit the authentication request :

```
        var client = new RestClient(m_baseUrl);
        
        var request = new RestRequest("https://dummyserver.com/api/auth", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("client_id", apiCredentials.ApiKey, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", apiCredentials.ApiSecret, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        IRestResponse response = await client.ExecutePostTaskAsync(request);
```

Since it is a distributed application, I don't have much info on the client request. Telemetry just confirms that the authentication failed.

Is it possible (known bug) that RestSharp transformed this request into a GET?

And, second question, is there any difference on the request being created with those two syntaxes:

- request.AddParameter("client_id", apiCredentials.ApiKey, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
- request.AddParameter("client_id", apiCredentials.ApiKey);

I need parameters to be submitted as form-data for security purposes.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible that a `POST` request gets executed as `GET`. Consider that you have some code (not the code from your question), which does that. Even using `ExecutePost` is redundant when you explicitly set the request type in the `RestRequest` constructor.

Concerning the second question, there's no real difference. The default parameter type is `GetOrPost`. I also believe that we use `multipart/form-data` for `POST` requests by default where there's no JSON or XML body.

You can easily find it by looking at the code of RestSharp.

Answer (score 0):

Although weird, I've experienced a similar issue with you.

My solution is to use ExecuteAsPost():

```
var response = client.ExecuteAsPost(request, "POST");
```